# How to implement chain search in sikuli script

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script

Can anyone give an advice how to implement using Sikuli analog of Selenium chain element search like `driver.findElement().findElement();`

1. first step: finding area
2. second step find element in this area

Answer (score 0):

Victor Iurkov,

**1.** You should create a Region and assign to a variable (use Region button from Sikuli IDE panel)

**2.** Use the variable and apply find() method

**It should look like:**

```
yourRegion = Region(2157,169,1049,148) 
yourRegion.find("desired-ui-element.png").highlight(2)
```

**Note:** Region(2157,169,1049,148) can be created manualy or via Region button in Sikuli IDE